# Voltage value changed after a while at the output of voltage regulator (TPS5430ddar)

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, gsm

I want to convert 7.4 V to 3.8 V.

Voltage regulator works correctly for a few minutes(appromaxitely 3 minutues). The problem is output voltage level of regulator steps up to 4.9V after a few minutes.

[image]The regulator is connected to a gsm module which has  a peak current of 2 A. The schematic of circuit is attached.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks...

Comment: Is it driving any load? If not, does a small load (like a 100 ohm or 1 kilohm resistor) make any difference?

Comment: We need more information.  The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvs632h/slvs632h.pdf) should be in the question, along with at least the load.  Do you have a picture of the circuit you are testing?  How does the load change with time?  Did you obey the solder temperature guidelines?  How are you testing it?

Comment: Add dummy load to the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of occasions like this are due to requiring a minimum load on the output. For instance the internal FET for this device will always switch on for typically a minmum of 150 ns at 500 kHz. This will always pass energy per cycle through to the output load and if the load doesn't take enough current the output will rise above the designed value.

You say the GSM module takes a peak of 2A but what is the average current consumption when the regulator starts to fail?

For instance, if the load current were only (say) 100 mA (average), using the formula for minimum value of inductor on page 15 of the DS you'd have to choose a value of 185 uH - you have 22 uH and , if 100mA were your average current then your circuit would do exactly what you describe as the current falls below about 1A.

Answer (score 0):

The regulator may be getting too hot and not reacting well to that.  I see that it is a switcher, so at least it's not dissipating 7.2 W like a linear regulator would.

Check the datasheet to see what the maximum current is.  This chip apparently contains the switch, so has some maximum current you shouldn't exceed.

Switcher aren't intended to get too hot, so often don't have thermal shutdown like linear regulators do.  You have to make sure none of the parameters specified in the datasheet are violated.  If any of them are, then you can't rely on any of the specs, including output regulation.

Without datasheet details, it's hard to guess what may be going on.  Start by checking all nodes with a scope to see if any of them don't look right.  Does this chip have a minimum load requirement?